# Sending email to address not set

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

I have this code

```
 var mail = new MailMessage(
                "from@from.com",
                "to@to.com",
                "subject",
                "body");
 mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("from@from.com"));

 var client = new SmtpClient();

 client.Send(mail);
```

In my web.config file I have

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="no-reply@no-reply.com">
        <network host="smtp.live.com" password="mypassword" port="587" userName="myemailaddress@hotmail.com" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

The problem is this: The to address of the email that gets sent to **to@to.com** is not **from@from.com** but instead is **myemailaddress@hotmail.com**.  When I hit reply to the email address then because I have this line:

```
mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("from@from.com"));
```

The reply to email address does get set to **from@from.com**.

What I want is:

1. The reply to email address to be **from@from.com** (as it is now)
2. The to email address to be **from@from.com** as well.

Right now, it seems to anyone receiving the email that the email has come from **myemailaddress@hotmail.com**.  I thought that the configuration in the web.config that I added was only for authenticating against the **smtp.live.com** mail server and that the email address wouldn't be used in the email being sent.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` You're not sending it through your own `from.com` mailserver. Microsoft (and most other major mail hosts) isn't going to allow you to intentionally spoof the sender address.

Comment: I see, and so do I need to set up my own email server?

Comment: ...or, send through a mailserver that doesn't require authentication. Or, if you actually own the `from.com` domain you're referring to, your existing DNS/web host may also provide this functionality. If you *don't* own that domain, you're effectively sending spam, and your messages may be flagged by the recipient mailservers. Essentially, don't "lie".

Comment: I see.  The from email address will be different for each email sent.  So there will be a wide variety of domains.  Does sendgrid require authentication?

Comment: `from email address will be different for each email sent` Do you, as the sender, own each of the different domains? If not, you shouldn't be sending them to look like they're coming from those domains.

Comment: Well, it's like this.  I have made a contact us page.  The user types their email address into the form and I use this as the from address.  If I don't do that how would I know who to send a reply back to?

Comment: `how would I know` That's a perfect use of `reply-to`, which you said is already working for you. Ultimately, intentionally spoofing the sender address is frowned upon, but is very possible (take a look at roughly 100% of all spam).

Comment: but you did say that if I use an smtp server that doesn't require authentication then I could do what I want, right?

Comment: Potentially, yes. Whether or not spoofing the sender addresses violates their terms of service, however, is another matter.

Comment: [Oren's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22797594/1454048) really is the most technically correct. What you're trying to do is probably not the best way to go about this.

Comment: How do all the other contact us pages all over the internet work then?

Comment: They typically hook into a system specifically developed for corporate contact ([Request Tracker](http://www.bestpractical.com/rt/), for example), and likely would not send an actual email message via SMTP with a crafted `from:` address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a guide you can use to set up your own SMTP server. Assuming you own "from.com" this will resolve your issue.

[Have a look at the MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b83ac7t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If you need to send email from many different domains you can configure virtual SMTP servers for each domain. Have a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b83ac7t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If you do not own the domains that you are attempting to send mail from then it will look like you are spoofing the sender address.

Comment: from.com is only an example.  There will be a wide variety of domains that I will send emails from.

Comment: But I will not know which domains the emails will come from.  I need to therefore support any and all domains.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the fact that you cannot do what you want to do with `any and all` domains.